# How do I test Data Source on Glassfish Localhost:8080?

Tags: jsp, netbeans, glassfish, localhost, datasource

I'm using Netbeans to put together an eCommerce. I'm now at the point of testing the data source on Glassfish localhost:8080. I created a unique .jsp file for that and towards the end added a DB Report with the following query statements:

```
<sql:query var="result" dataSource="jdbc/ecommerce">
    SELECT * FROM category, product 
    WHERE category.id = product_category.product_id
</sql:query>
```

When I right-click on the testDataSource and run it, it output successfully in my web-browser but then I get this error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: 
    SELECT * FROM category, product 
    WHERE category.id = product_category.product_id
: Unknown column 'product_category.product_id' in 'where clause'
```

root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'product_category.product_id' in 'where clause'

Now obviously the problem is easy to understand "the column is unknown" which means it doesn't seem to recognize what I want him to. I have tried to change the name of columns and try match it, I still receive same error...

Maybe I'm starting to get tired... I have no clue what to do...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are having product after the FROM while in bottom you are calling product_category. Call product_category after FROM.

Must be something like

SELECT * FROM category, product_category

WHERE

category.id = product_category.product_id